# Why is my push function not reflecting the changes on the showColumn() function?

Tags: c++, stack

I just started programming in CPP a few weeks ago, so please do forgive me if I am making rookie mistakes. I am trying to make a Connect Four program with stacks of array implementation. (Reason why im using stack is that the coins would directly go to the bottom since stack is LIFO).

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const int stSize = 6;

class myStack // class for myStack. Each column is a stack.
{
 private:
     int arr[stSize];
     int inUse;
 public:
 myStack ()
 {
     inUse = -1;
 }

 int getstSize() {
     return stSize;
 }

 int getInUse() {
  return inUse;
 }

void showColumn() {
    for (int p=inUse; p>=0; p--) {
        arr[p] = 'O';
    }
    printf("======\n");
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[5]);
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[4]);
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[3]);
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[2]);
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[1]);
    printf("| %c |\n",arr[0]);
    printf("======\n");
}

void push(char data) {
 if (inUse == stSize-1) {
     printf("Error. Stack's full.");
     return;
 }
 else {
     inUse = inUse +1;
     arr[inUse] = data;
 }
}

};

 int main()
 {
    myStack test;
    printf("Test your stack by pushing things here.\n");
    test.push('x');
    test.push('o');
    test.push('o');
    test.push('o');
    test.push('o');
    test.push('x');
    test.showColumn();

    return 0;
 }
```

Initially, the column is supposed to be

```
======
| O |
| O |
| O |
| O |
| O |
| O |
======
```

but when I push stuff, it should look something like:

```
======
| X |
| T |
| T |
| T |
| X |
| X |
======
```

But even after pushing, the slots are empty! Why?

Comment: `arr[p] = 'O';` is your problem. Better rewrite the showColumn() function. It should not change any value in `arr` also it should  not blindly print the first 6 values in `arr` Start with your for loop and print instead of setting values..

Comment: you should consider to rename the method into `overwriteAllDataAndThenShowColumns()` :P

Comment: The `for` inside `showColumn` is changing whole stack's value

Comment: Thanks everyone. I realize how silly my question was. I've been up all night working on homework (although this project is just for my personal enjoyment/experience), and I am kinda tired right now, so maybe that's why I overlooked this logical error.

Comment: My advice is to learn how to properly use your debugger.